# Design considerations when automatically signing and submitting Cardano transactions

Tags: transaction, security

Automating transactions (eg an Oracle that regularly publishes meta data to the blockchain) require that we balance the necessity to sign each transaction using a signing key with the security of the keys themselves.

What approaches have you and your projects used to tackle this problem? And, how does the approach change as an application's developer team grows?